# Orchard CMS - theming

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, theming

I have some questions regarding theming Orchard CMS. So, let's begin... I have a website that will have 5 pages and some of them have different layouts.

Pages and zones within it:

**Homepage** - Content, TripelFirst, TripelSecond, TripelThird

**Concept** and **Rentals** page - Content, AsideFirst, AsideSecond

**Press** and **Service Department** page - Content, AsideFirst, AsideSecond (different layout then the previous two pages)

Note: Even though all of the pages have the Content zone, except Homepage none of the pages uses it. Other pages only have HTML widgets located in one of the zones.

1) I've read that it is possible to create the layout for the specific ID, the problem is I can't find that ID to create the layout for specific ID.

2) As you can see, couple of pages have the same layout, how to assign them to the specific layout? For example, if I create the layout for **Concept** and **Rentals** page how can I assign the specific layout to them and also how can I assign the layout to **Press** and **Service Department** pages?

3) How to add the class tag to the body? The problem is that Orchard CMS creates the body before everything else so it isn't contained in the layout cshtml files.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. when you edit the page in the admin, the url will look something like `http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/Admin/Contents/Edit/16`

   **16** is the id here.
2. Several things you can do. Easiest is to use this module: http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Orchard.LayoutSelector

   Alternatively, you could programmatically create alternates based on arbitrary criteria: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/12/14/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms.aspx

   Finally, you can often avoid to have to create an actual separate layout by just varying what widgets go where, using layers.
3. The body tag is in `document.cshtml`, which you can override in your own theme.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a go tomorrow, but as you are one of the Orchard developers quality of the answer isn't questionable. May I suggest a specialized forum for Orchard as the community is growing. When I get some experience in theming I'll write a tutorial.

Comment: @Hrvach Hmm I really think stackoverflow would be the perfect place for discussing orchard, the codeplex forums aren't fun and the mailing list is nice but can get annoying to shoot support emails like that into peoples inboxes. Would be nice to have a little link on orchardproject.net to SO.

Comment: @giddy: believe it or not, more than two years ago, when the project was in its infancy, we contacted Jeff and asked him if we could/should do exactly that and he strongly discouraged us from doing it. In a nutshell I hope I don't misrepresent him by saying he doesn't think it's appropriate for SO to be used as the "official" forum for any product. Still, it's more than fine to ask questions here if you prefer, we monitor the orchardcms tag as well as the Discussions on CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Not sure what you mean by `ID`? If you click `Widgets` on the DashBoard, there are Layers there. A layer is a collection of widgets that will activate for a specific thing, Like the authenticated Layer will display those widgets you define when a user is authenticated.

Expanding on (1) and for (2), you will be able to create a new layout by adding widgets to a layer.

Check out:
[Tagged Layer Rule](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NogginBox.Tagged) - Allows you to add widgets based on a tag. Now, you can add pages for *concepts* and *rentals* and then specify a layer for these tags, within that layer, you can add any widgets you like. These will only appear when that tag is encountered.

Also check out:
[Content Type Layer Rule](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.CyberStride.TypeLayerRule) - Haven't tried this, but it falls on the same lines.

**3.** To customize the look there is something called Shapes. Each Zone I **think** has a corresponding `cshtml` files. You can even use the ShaperBuilder to even render html in code, again, don't know too much about this but I can tell you, you need to look into these articles.

- [Using shapes as Html helpers in Orchard](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/using-shapes-as-html-helpers-in-orchard)
- [Using shapes as Html helpers in Orchard](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/using-shapes-as-html-helpers-in-orchard)
- [Taking over list rendering in Orchard](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx)
- [Dispatching Orchard shapes to arbitrary zones](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx)

HTH, I'll try and contact some orchard folk that are on SO.

Answer (score 1):

So to help you out here

1. The ID of the Home Page is always 11 for a fresh install though I imagine that you can delete the home page and create a new one and give it another ID.  To find the ID of the other pages open up the DB and look at the Content Items.
2. I know of no way to apply Layouts other than by ID so just duplicate the layout pages as you have so few pages.
3. I would just use a small jQuery script

   $(document).ready(function{
    $('body').addClass('SomeClass');
   });